# ¿Cómo hacer que no se pueda cerrar un modal sin aceptar términos?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, modal

Necesito hacer que el modal que se abre al cargar no se pueda cerrar a menos que el check de aceptar esté checkeado sé como comprobar que esté checkeado pero lo qe no es como hacer que no se pueda cerrar el modal, ya que con clicar fuera de este es suficiente para que se cierre...

```js
setTimeout(
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#condiciones_rgpd').modal('show');
  }),
  5000
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="condiciones_rgpd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lbcondiciones_rgpd" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="condiciones_rgpdDiv">
          <h1>HOLA</h1>
          <input type="checkbox"> Aceptar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No hagas un modal como tal, si utilizas los de bootstrap, ya vienen preparados para que al clicar fuera se desvanezcan, mi consejo, create uno propio, así las configuraciones serán las que tú quieras

Comment: Como puedo hacer un modal propio? El de bootstrap me viene bien por eso mismo, porque está hecho para ser cómodo pero necesito uno que no se cierre... Gracias

Comment: Creas un `<div>` con una id que tenga en el css por defecto `display:none`, con posición fija y defines las coordenadas, y al pulsar un botón de la página o disparar un evento X cambie el `display:none` por `display:box` o la que mejor se adapte a tus necesidades, y para cerrarlo disparas un evento con las acciones que tú quieras que se cierre el modal (pinchar fuera, darle a una X, boton aceptar....), y en el handler del evento compruebas el valor del check, si no está pulsado, no cierras el modal, e incluso puedes añadir un mensaje de aviso. Es más dificil cambiar lo de bootstrap que esto :)

Comment: La única pega es esa, que tienes que currartelo tú, sé que da pereza, de hecho yo uso bootstrap siempre que mis necesidades me lo permiten. Pero a veces he tenido que hacer cosas que ya hay en bootstrap solo porque no se adhieren a lo que yo necesito en concreto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes configurar fácilmente un modal de bootstrap para que se comporte del modo que necesitas.

Podes utilizar las propiedades `keyboard: false` para que al presionar escape el modal no se cierre, además de `backdrop: 'static'` para que al clickear fuera del modal no se cierre, por último solo bastaría que agregues un `listener` y cerrarlo al presionar el `checkbox`

Sería algo como lo siguiente

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){

  $('#condiciones_rgpd').modal(
  {
    keyboard: false,
    backdrop: 'static'
  });

});

$(':input').on('click',function(){

  $('#condiciones_rgpd').modal('hide');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="condiciones_rgpd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lbcondiciones_rgpd" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="condiciones_rgpdDiv">
          <h1>HOLA</h1>
          <input type="checkbox"> Aceptar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 4):

Aquí lo tienes, mi consejo es que cambies el checkbox, por que al no dejar salir mas que aceptando el checkbox es mas natural que sea un botón.

¿Que se hace? se añade este comando "data-backdrop='static'" que lo que hace es omitir el cerrado por click fuera del modal.

```js
$('#aceptar').on('click',function(){
  $('#condiciones_rgpd').modal('hide');
})

setTimeout(
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#condiciones_rgpd').modal('show');
  }),
  5000
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="condiciones_rgpd" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lbcondiciones_rgpd" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="condiciones_rgpdDiv">
          <h1>HOLA</h1>
          <button id="aceptar"> Aceptar </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Otra buena posibilidad :)